# Hibernate SQL запрос на specification spring jpa

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, запрос, spring-jpa

решил переделать запрос на спецификацию spring jpa, никак не могу победить подзапросы чтобы их реализовать на спецификации, есть следующий запрос:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a FROM A a, B b FETCH JOIN a.fieldC FETCH JOIN a.fieldD
   WHERE a.field=:field and 
      (SELECT COUNT(b) FROM B b WHERE b.a.id=a.id and b.status=STATUS) = 0 
      and b.a.id=a.id and 
      (SELECT COUNT(b) FROM B b WHERE b.a.id=a.id and b.field.id=1) > 0
      and a.date>:date order by a.fieldToOrder desc;
```

Получается все сделать, но как только дело доходит до двух подзапросов в запросе, у меня ничего не выходит.
Может есть у кого какие идеи? Спасибо

Comment: никто не знает как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вопрос решён с помощью subquery и join.
Пример для части запроса, прошу прощения, что не могу скинуть всё преобразование, так как его нужно долго собирать в коде в одно и заменять названия сущностей - думаю по этому куску кода понятно как реализовать оставшуюся specification:

```
(SELECT COUNT(b) FROM B b WHERE b.a.id=a.id and b.status=STATUS) = 0

Subquery sub = cq.subquery(Long.class);
Root subRoot = sub.from(B.class);
sub.select(cb.count(subRoot));
sub.where(cb.equal(root.get("ID"), subRoot.get(A).get("ID")),
                    cb.equal(subRoot.get("status"), STATUS));
return cb.equal(sub, 0L);
```

Comment: Не могли бы Вы дать более подробный ответ? Спасибо.

Comment: добавил ответ...